# Servlet methods doesnt redirect page

Tags: java, servlets, http-redirect

Im creating an application and im starting by the log in of users, i'm trying that when they log in the page redirect to another page, im trying to do this with response.sendRedirect but this is not working, it just shows the code of the html in the console log. I would like to know why is this happening

Login class post method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        JSONObject reqBody = new JSONObject(request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Database db = new Database("postgresql", "localhost", "5432", "Reader", "postgres", "kush");
        if(session.isNew()) {
            if(db.checkUser(reqBody.getString("email"), reqBody.getString("pass")) == true) {
                json.put("status", "new session, welcome back");
                storeValue(reqBody.getString("email"), reqBody.getString("pass"), reqBody.getBoolean("admin"), session);
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/loggedin.html");
            } else {
                json.put("status", "username or password incorrect");
                session.invalidate();
            }
        } else {
            json.put("status", "session updated");
            storeValue(reqBody.getString("email"), reqBody.getString("pass"), reqBody.getBoolean("admin"), session);
        }
        out.println(json.toString());
    }
```

I have tried to use

```
response.sendRedirect("loggedin.html");
```

or

```
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", "loggedin.html");
```

or

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
sc.getRequestDispatcher("/loggedin.html").forward(request, response);
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/loggedin.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Reader/loggedin.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Im calling the get and post methods with xml http request

loggedin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login successful</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Reader | Project</title>
<script src = 'js/XHR.js'><</script>
</head>

<p><input id="email" type="text" name="em"></p>
<p><input id="password" type="password" name="pw"></p>
<p>
<p> Admin user? 
 <select id="admin">
    <option value="true">Si</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
</p>

<button onclick='sendValue()'>Send</button>
<button onclick='getValue()'>Get</button>
<button onclick='deleteValue()'>Delete</button>
<body>
<script>
var wrapper = new XHR();
function element(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function sendValue() {
    var email = element('email').value;
    var password = element('password').value;
    var is_admin = element('admin').value;
    wrapper.post('./Login',{email:email, pass:password, admin:is_admin},{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

}

function getValue() {
    wrapper.get('./Login',{},{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
}

function deleteValue() {
    wrapper.get('./Logout',{},{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

XHR.js

```
function XHR() {

    var jsonToParams = json => {
        var res = "";
        for (var attr in json) {
            if (res === "") {
                res = attr + "=" + json[attr];
            } else {
                res += "&" + attr + "=" + json[attr];
            }
        }
        return res;
    };

    this.send = function(method, url, params, headers) { 
        return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
            var wrapper = new XMLHttpRequest();
            wrapper.open(method, url);
            wrapper.onload = function()  {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    fullfill(wrapper.responseText);
                } else {
                    reject({ status: this.status, statusText: wrapper.statusText });
                }
            };

            for (var header in headers) {
                wrapper.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
            }

            if (method === 'POST') {
                wrapper.send(JSON.stringify(params));
            } else {
                wrapper.send();
            }
        });
    }

    this.get = function(url, params, headers) {
        params=typeof params==="string" ? params : jsonToParams(params);
        url += "?" + params;
        this.send('GET', url, params, headers)
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    this.post = function(url, params, headers) {
        this.send('POST', url, params, headers)
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: How type page did you used ? JSP?

Comment: @jhonatan2760 i used html

Comment: try to use JSP. 
I dont k'now if redirect works only on simple html page

Comment: ***"Im calling the get and post methods with xml http request"***. Do you mean calling via AJAX? If that's so, then your AJAX script needs to do something with the redirected content. The browser in this case wont see the redirect in order to load the login page.

Comment: @tsolakp i updated the question with the XHR i made to do the methods

Comment: @jhonatan2760 i did, but still doesnt redirect it just gives the code of the html in the console log

Comment: I am not Javascript expert but it looks like you are calling `post` method that just writes into console (`console.log(data);`).Instead of using Javascript just declare a form in your HTML that will post to your servlet. In this case browser witll see redirect and show the loggedin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work for you :)

```
<form action="loggedin.html">
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```